# sql (oracle) counting number of overlapping intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

I have the following problem:

Given the following table `test` in an oracle sql database:

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | start | stop |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 1  |   A  |   1   |  5   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 2  |   A  |   2   |  6   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 3  |   A  |   5   |  8   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 4  |   A  |   9   |  10  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 5  |   B  |   3   |  6   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 6  |   B  |   4   |  8   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 7  |   B  |   1   |  2   |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

I would like to find the number of overlapping intervals (endpoints included) [start, stop] `n_overlap`, for all `id` having the same `name`, i.e.:

```
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| id | name | start | stop | n_overlap |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 1  |   A  |   1   |  5   |     3     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 2  |   A  |   2   |  6   |     3     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 3  |   A  |   4   |  8   |     3     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 4  |   A  |   9   |  10  |     1     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 5  |   B  |   3   |  6   |     2     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 6  |   B  |   4   |  8   |     2     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
| 7  |   B  |   1   |  2   |     1     |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from test t2
        where t2.name = t.name and
              t2.start < t.end and
              t2.end > t.start
       ) as num_overlaps
from test t;
```

Comment: The last condition in `where` should actually be `t2.end > t.start`