# sql (oracle) count and sum within the same select/where query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, where-clause

With reference to the following and correctly answered question:
[sql (oracle) counting number of overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484909/sql-oracle-counting-number-of-overlapping-intervals)

Given the following table `test` in an oracle sql database:

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | start | stop |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 1  |   A  |   1   |  5   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 2  |   A  |   2   |  6   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 3  |   A  |   5   |  8   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 4  |   A  |   9   |  10  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 5  |   B  |   3   |  6   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 6  |   B  |   4   |  8   |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 7  |   B  |   1   |  2   |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

I would now like to find the number of overlapping intervals (endpoints included) [start, stop] `n_overlap` as well as the sum of the `stop` values for all `id` having the same `name`, i.e.:

```
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| id | name | start | stop | n_overlap | sum_stops  |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 1  |   A  |   1   |  5   |     3     |    19      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 2  |   A  |   2   |  6   |     3     |    19      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 3  |   A  |   4   |  8   |     3     |    19      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 4  |   A  |   9   |  10  |     1     |    10      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 5  |   B  |   3   |  6   |     2     |    14      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 6  |   B  |   4   |  8   |     2     |    14      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
| 7  |   B  |   1   |  2   |     1     |     2      |
+----+------+-------+------+-----------+------------+
```

I tried this solution, which works:

```
select t.*,
   (select count(*)
    from test t2
    where t2.name = t.name and
          t2.start <= t.stop and
          t2.stop >= t.start
   ) as n_overlap,
   (select sum(stop)
    from test t2
    where t2.name = t.name and
          t2.start <= t.stop and
          t2.stop >= t.start
   ) as sum_stops 
from test t;
```

But, is there a way to condense the two select/where queries, using e.g.:

```
select t.*,
   (select count(*) as n_overlap, sum(stop) as sum_stops
    from test t2
    where t2.name = t.name and
          t2.start <= t.stop and
          t2.stop >= t.start
   ) 
from test t;
```

which raises a `too many values` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.start, t.stop, COUNT(t2.name) AS n_overlap, SUM(t2.stop) AS sum_stops
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.name = t.name AND t2.start <= t.stop AND t2.stop >= t.start
GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.start, t.stop
```

Output:

```
id  name    start   stop    n_overlap   sum_stops
1   A       1       5       3           19
2   A       2       6       3           19
3   A       5       8       3           19
4   A       9       10      1           10
5   B       3       6       2           14
6   B       4       8       2           14
7   B       1       2       1           2
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick. It gives an error `not a GROUP BY expression`, but it works if I remove `t.*` from `SELECT`

Comment: Sorry, used to MySQL's lax `GROUP BY` rules. If you want all the `t.*` values (other than just id) you should be able to put them all in the `GROUP BY` e.g. `GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.start, t.stop`

Comment: thank you @Nick. It works if I list explicitly all the columns/values in both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, but it does not, if I simply use `SELECT t.*, COUNT(t2.name) AS...` and `GROUP BY t.*`, which might be a problem when there are many columns/values.

Comment: @MarcoC I've edited my answer to reflect that. As you say, it's a pain when there are many columns & values. The only way around that is to use a subquery as Salman proposes in his answer. You may want to accept that instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT test.*, n_overlap, sum_stops
FROM test
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m.id, COUNT(o.id) AS n_overlap, SUM(o.stop) AS sum_stops
    FROM test AS m
    INNER JOIN test AS o ON
        /* m.id <> o.id AND */
        m.name = o.name AND
        m.stop >= o.start AND
        o.stop >= m.start
    GROUP BY m.id
) AS sq ON test.id = sq.id
```

I might add that your expected output considers any given row overlapping with itself (see row #4). You might want to exclude the row matching itself.